# 404handler for cmsapp pages - django

Tags: python, django

I have a page which can be fed with different cms apphooks.. like news, videos etc..

my concern is now to add a 404handler which should redirect to startpage if 404 happens.

I did in my dev_settings.py:

```
from settings import * 
DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mydomain.com']
```

and in main urls.py: (i put this handler first in app's urls.py, but it wasnot seen at all. so it must be in main urls.py, i guess)

```
handler404 = 'mysite.newsapp.views.handler404'
```

and in news app's views,

```
def handler404(request):
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

this is showing many 302's instead of redirecting to startpage and after a little while browser is showing, that this page isnot available. i assume that the there is endless redirect which is causing this.

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect all 404 requests to index, you can do it this way:

```
def handler404(request):
    return redirect('index-view-name')
```

Solution by Mithu just shows the same template - and I think that it is not a good idea - you will then have same content on the index page and any non-existing random URL that you can imagine - maybe the search engines won't like it...

Comment: I know this and this doesnot work! Please read the question first. It is about apphooks, not normal pages